# sudo apt-get update failes with an Hash Sum mismatch error

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, proxy

As can be seen on the title, I got the "Failed to fetch... Hash Sum mismatch" Error. I have tried this method:

1. Deleting /var/lib/apt/lists/* does not work...
2. Thinking, if I'm behind a proxy, I tried fixing "Hash Sum Mismatch" like this:

   By Creating a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy with this content

   Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;

   Acquire::http::No-Cache true;

   Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
3. I tried several other solutions provided on askubuntu however, it doesn't work.

Have a look at my error on the terminal.

[Screenshot of the Error obtained in the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBAsP.png)

Comment: You may want to go to the directory: "/etc/apt/" and identify the list with address that results in the failure, and then delete that address. I just had to do that with a microsoft address, because they do not always keep their packages up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this might be the issue of caches within your ISP. These packages are distributed across multiple locations for making available globally, due to such this packages sometimes not get the updates at a given time in some location so thus you faced this hash sum error.

I would recommend you to perform this action via changing proxy address/ VPN which will change the IP.

Comment: exactly, this happens with broadband providers in India, alternatively changing the server from main server or Indian server to an alternative server for example Italy, solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This solution finally worked out for me:

1. sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
2. sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
3. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1785778